# Best place to initialize analytics libs in React 16.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm building a new React 16.5 app with Redux and want to integrate some third party services for analytics and error tracking. I don't want to use their npm or react plugins at this point and just want to integrate via pure JS.

All of them require loading a lib which I do in the `<head>` section outside of my React app package, and then some sort of `init()` function that should be called on page load.

In the past, I've always called these initialization functions in `componentWillMount` of my top level component, because that function is guaranteed to run. I noticed however that it is now [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

**What is the best practice spot to initialize analytics libs in React 16.x?**

I don't want to do it in `componentDidMount` because if there are any errors right off the bat and the component never mounts, I won't get any page views or errors reporting back.

Should I just initialize them outside of all my components in `App.jsx`? Please let me know if I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: typically, an analytics package will expose global variables, e.g. GA exposes `ga`

Comment: Yes but for example with Sentry: https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/quickstart/?platform=browser. Where do I call `Sentry.init`?

Comment: so it's exposing `Sentry` and yes, you should call its `init` function in `App.jsx`

Comment: I think it should be done in index.js before initializing store and calling ReactDOM.render

Comment: Have you checked out react-helmet ? We use it in production combined with middleware that fires when we initialize the application just like @Valerii suggested. You can make a component that includes all the scripts you need to load in the head, and you can also add it to other components if you need to update or add a script.